# how to give negative conditions in tf.where tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, indices

I want to extract the indices of a tensor, where a certain conditions are not met.

For example, I want the indices of a tensor rows where all columns are not zero.

```
idx = tf.where(!(x[:,0]==x[:,1]==x[:,2]==0))
```

Is there any other better way to extract such info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the indices of tensors whose all elements are different from 0 amounts to looking for tensors whose sum of the absolute values of the elements is different from 0 (in the case where the elements of your tensors can be negative).

```
x = tf.constant([[2.0, 0., 4.0], [0., 0., 2.0], [-2.0, 0., 1.0]])

idx = tf.where(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(x), axis=0)!=0)
```

Output:

```
>>>print(idx)
tf.Tensor(
[[0]
 [2]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=int64)
```

`tf.abs` is useless if all values are positive.

You can also use `tf.math.logical_not` which reverses the condition:

```
>>>print(tf.math.logical_not(x==0))
tf.Tensor(
[[ True False  True]
 [False False  True]
 [ True False  True]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=bool)
```

Comment: thanks. I used       
idx = tf.where(tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(y_true), axis=1)!=0) # all of (x,y,z) are not zero


y_true = tf.gather_nd(y_true, idx)